# How to send data from HTML form input type number to a variable in app views.py Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Here is input type number in template file

```html
<form action="" method="get">
    <input class="form-control m-3 w-50 mx-auto" type="text" name="question" id="question" placeholder="Enter Something...">
    <input type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control m-3 w-50 mx-auto" />
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-3" type="submit" value="Check Now">
</form>
```

I want to get the number that is selected by the user.

I need to store the number variable value to custom_number variable in views.py file. How can I do this?

```py
def your_view(request):
    number = request.GET.get('number_input')
    number = int(number)

custom_number = number

def home_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET" and 'question' in request.GET:
        question = request.GET.get('question')
        data = custom_funct(question)
        context = {'data': data}
    else:
        context = {}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An input without a name will not send anything back to the server, so that is step 1:

```html
<input name="number_input" type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control m-3 w-50 mx-auto" />
```

Step two is to extract it by using `request.GET.get()`:

```py
# views.py

def home_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET" and 'question' in request.GET:
        question = request.GET.get('question')
        number = int(request.GET.get('number_input'))
        data = custom_funct(question)
        context = {'data': data}
    else:
        context = {}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

NOTE: your `custom_number = number` will **not** work since it is outside of a view.  I was using `your_view` as an example only, since I did not know what the name of your view was.  You should include my suggestion within your `home_view`, just like you already have done with `question = request.GET('question')`.

Comment: My mistake, @Raj I edited my answer.  It should be `request.GET.get('input_number')`.

Comment: Does that mean The given number is now stored in the number variable? How can I get it?

Comment: Yes, the variable `number` *should* have the value submitted in the form, @Raj .  It is in the format of string but you can change it, for example, if it's an integer, `int(number)`.

Comment: I have edited my post. Could you please check now. I need to store number value in custom_number variable. Did I make something wrong?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer to explain, @Raj but you cannot use this `custom_number` outside the view.  I was using `your_view` as an example.  You can get the number in your `home_view`, you do not need another view.  Please see my edited post.